# NetLogo hatch and die

Tags: netlogo, die

I want to make turtles move around and look for a partner (a turtle that is not already partnered that is on the same patch) , and when they found one I want them to hatch a certain number of turtles and then die. But what happens is that when I start the simulation, all turtles die at the first tick. What am I doing wrong?

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    partner-up
  ]
  birth
  death
  tick
end


to partner-up
  if (not partnered?) [
    rt (random-float 90 - random-float 90) fd 1
    set partner one-of (turtles-at 0 0) with [ not partnered? ]
    if partner != nobody [
      set partnered? true
      ask partner [
        set partnered? true
        set partner myself
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to birth
  let partnered-turtles turtles with [ partnered? ]
  ask partnered-turtles [
    calculate-score
    hatch (score + 1)
  ]
end

to death
  let partnered-turtles turtles with [ partnered? ]
  ask partnered-turtles [
    die
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things stand out- one is the call to `one-of (turtles-at 0 0) with [ not partnered? ]`. This includes ALL turtles on the patch that you indicate (equivalent to `turtles-here`), which means including the turtle executing the command. I think you want `other turtles-here` or `(other turtles-at 0 0)`.

Next, your 'baby turtles' are inheriting all the attributes of their parents, including values in their `partnered?` and `partner` variables. So, the turtles are being hatched with `partnered? = true`, and so when the call to `death` occurs in your `go` procedure, they qualify as `partnered-turtles` and therefore die. To correct this, you can explicitly set the variables for your hatched turtles- for example:

```
to birth
  let partnered-turtles turtles with [ partnered? ]
  ask partnered-turtles [
    let score 1
    hatch (score + 1) [
      set partnered? false
      set partner nobody
    ]
  ]
end
```

Also, not sure if this is intentional but wanted to point out that both 'partners' will `hatch` an offspring. If you want a more standard biological model you may want only one of the parents to hatch.

Revised toy model:

```
turtles-own [ partnered? partner]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  ask n-of 10 patches [
    sprout 1 [
      set partnered? false
      set partner nobody
    ]
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    partner-up
  ]
  birth
  death
  tick
end


to partner-up
  if (not partnered?) [
    rt (random-float 90 - random-float 90) fd 1
    set partner one-of (other turtles-at 0 0) with [ not partnered? ]
    if partner != nobody [
      set partnered? true
      ask partner [
        set partnered? true
        set partner myself
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to birth
  let partnered-turtles turtles with [ partnered? ]
  ask partnered-turtles [
    let score one-of [ 0 1 ]
    hatch (score + 1) [
      set partnered? false
      set partner nobody
    ]
  ]
end

to death
  let partnered-turtles turtles with [ partnered? ]
  ask partnered-turtles [
    die
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for all your indications. Yes, I needed exactly the `other` command...so I should write something like this `set partner one-of (other turtles-at 0 0) with [ not partnered? ]` right? Regarding the hatching, your observation is correct but that is handled in the _calculate-score_ function, so one of the two will get a -1 score and hatch 0 and the other one will hatch a number >= 1 (of course you could not know that as I did not include that function in my question, but thank you for noticing that  and trying to give additional suggestion)

Comment: @Deffo - Yes, that's exactly correct- sorry I didn't upload the actually-corrected code. Of course, your note about scoring to deal with hatched turtles makes good sense. Happy coding!